# Amazon and Google flavors

Tags: android, gradle

Amazon project gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}
```

while google project gradle looks like this:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
    }
```

Anybody know if it is possible to set up flavors in module gradle?
If it is impossible then is it possible to know the project gradle classpath in module gradle?